# Solutions to Black Scholes

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the black scholes equation,

$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t } + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2 } + ( r-q )S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S }-rV =0
$$

How do I show that if $V( S, t)$ is a solution, then $S(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S })$ is also a solution?

I tried substituting $S(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S })$ to the equation and working through the calculations but it doesn't seem to work out.

On a related note, how do we also show that for $ \beta = 1-2(r-q)/\sigma^2$,

$$
W(S, t) = S^\beta V(\frac{1}{S}, t)
$$

is also a solution?

The relevant partial derivatives are,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial S} & = \beta S^{\beta -1 }V- S^{\beta -2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\\
\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial S^2} & = S^{\beta -4}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} -2S^{\beta -3}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \beta(\beta -1 )S^{\beta-2}V
\end{align}
$$

So the various terms in the PDE are,

$$\begin{align}
(r-q)S\frac{\partial W}{\partial S} & = (r-q) \left[ \beta S^{\beta }V- S^{\beta -1}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right] \\
\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2W}{\partial S^2}& =\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\left[ S^{\beta -2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} -2S^{\beta -1}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \beta(\beta -1 )S^{\beta}V \right]
\end{align}
$$

I can see that $ (r-q) \beta S^{\beta }V$ in the top term cancels with $\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\beta(\beta -1 )S^{\beta}V $ in the bottom term.

So we end up with,

$$ 
(r-q)S\frac{\partial W}{\partial S}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2W}{\partial S^2}=-(r-q) S^{\beta -1}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\left[ S^{\beta -2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} -2S^{\beta -1}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right]
$$

But beyond this I kind of stuck despite trying various manipulations.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for the second part on $W(S,t)=S^\beta V(1/S,t)$, I've figured it out. Just some carelessness on my part when tossing terms around. It goes as follows...

The partial derivatives are,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial S} & = \beta S^{\beta -1 }V- S^{\beta -2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\\
\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial S^2} & =  \beta \left[ -S^{\beta-3}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + (\beta-1)S^{\beta-2}V \right] - \left[ -S^{\beta-4} \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + (\beta-2)S^{\beta -3}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right]
\end{align}$$

Let $x=1/S$ and factor out $S^\beta$,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial S} & = S^{\beta } \left[ \beta xV -x^2\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right]  \\
\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial S^2}& =  S^{\beta } \left[  \beta \left( -x^3\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + (\beta-1)x^2V \right)  -\left( -x^4\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} +(\beta-2)x^3\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)\right]
\end{align}$$
We exclude $S^{\beta} $ since it's a common factor for all terms. The PDE terms are,

$$\begin{align}
( r-q )S\frac{\partial W}{\partial S} & = ( r-q )x^{-1}\frac{\partial W}{\partial S} \\ & =  ( r-q )\left[ \beta V -x\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} \right]\\
\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial S^2} &= \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^{-2}\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial S^2}\\ &= \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \left[ \beta \left( -x\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + (\beta-1)V \right)  -\left( -x^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} +(\beta-2)x\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right) \right]
\end{align}$$

As mentioned earlier, the terms involving $V$ cancels, therefore
$$\begin{align}
 ( r-q )S\frac{\partial W}{\partial S}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial S^2} & =  -( r-q )\left[x\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right] + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\left[(2-2\beta)x\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}+x^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \right] \\& =-( r-q )\left[x\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right] +2( r-q )\left[x\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right] +\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}+( r-q )x\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}
\end{align}
$$

Combining with the other two terms we get,

$$
S^\beta \left[ \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}+( r-q )x\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} -rV  \right]=S^\beta.0=0
$$
Therefore we've shown that if $ V(S,t)$ is a solution to the Black Scholes PDE, then $W(S,t)=S^\beta V(1/S,t)$ is also solution.

Answer (score 4):

First note that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right) = \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + S \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial S^2}\left(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right) = 2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + S \frac{\partial^3 V}{\partial S^3} \; .$$

Then, take the derivative of the Black-Scholes equation with respect to $S$.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S } + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \left(2S\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + S^2 \frac{\partial^3 V}{\partial S^3}\right) + ( r-q )\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S } + S\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2 }\right)-r\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} =0 \; .$$

Using our first two identities, we identify the second and third term

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S } + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \left(S\frac{\partial^2}{\partial S^2}\left(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)\right) + ( r-q )\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)\right)-r\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} =0 \; .$$

Multiplying everything by S, we get

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S }\right) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial S^2}\left(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right) + ( r-q )S\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left(S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)-rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} =0 \; .$$

Comment: so it's not possible to go the forward direction and see that every cancels out to zero?

Comment: on a separate note this is also what they mean when they say that the black scholes operator and the operator $ S(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S } )$ commutes? is there somewhere with notes on this and finding commutative pairs in general?

Comment: About your second question, yes. So, it should be possible to solve the problem in the "forward direction", you'll just have to be more careful about collecting terms. I don't know any set of notes in particular, but the Black Scholes equation has been the subject of many treatises, books, articles. I'm sure you'd find something quickly with a simple Google search.

Comment: However, note that $S\frac{\partial}{\partial S}$ is the generator of scale transformations. The fact it commutes with the Black Scholes equation signifies the scale invariance of the latter. Considering the solutions of Black Scholes equations are related to the Brownian motion, this is no surprise as Brownian motion also exhibits scale invariance. Commutation relations, invariances and the like are the bread and butter of the theory of Lie groups & algebras.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t } + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2 } + ( r-q )S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S }-rV =0$$
We can regroup
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t } + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \left( S\frac{\partial }{\partial S}\right)^2  V + ( r-q - \sigma^2/2 )S\frac{\partial V }{\partial S }  -rV =0.$$

Now observe that $S \frac{\partial}{\partial S}$ commutes with all the coefficients (i.e. terms in front) of $V$ since it commutes itself and doesn't interact with $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}.$

The result is now immediate.

(see my book Concepts etc section 5.8)